# Count Tables in phpmyadmin 4 - config file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

in phpmyadmin 3 in order to show the number of tables in the database you can add this line the config file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['CountTables']=true;
```

however it seems that this is deprecated in phpmyadmin 4, according to this: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#CountTables

> This item is outdated and applies only to versions prior to phpMyAdmin
>   4.0.0.

is there an alternative to this in phpmyadmin 4?

Comment: you might try to explain why you need to know the number of tables inside a database, because its a quite rare requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting tables was removed due to performance reasons. See the discussion on this [bug ticket](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3917/). So, the answer to you question is, no, there is no alternative for this directive in phpMyAdmin 4.0

Answer (score 2):

I've found a good workaround,
go to "..\phpmyadmin\libraries\List_Database.class.php"
comment 2 lines at 290 and 292

```
// if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['CountTables']) { //HERE
                $dbgroups[$group][$db]['num_tables'] = PMA_getTableCount($db);
          //  } //AND HERE
```

and voilà!